# Getting an invalid path error because friend pushed with a space at the end of his folder name

Tags: git, github, gitlab

My friend and I are working on a project. He added some files and pushed them, but he seems to have included a space at the end of his file name. When I try to pull it now, I get

```
error: invalid path 'Data_File /CMakeLists.txt'
```

Is there any way I can fix this by myself, because he isn't able to work today

Comment: Can you tell us which OS you and your friend are using?

Comment: I can't reproduce this problem on a ubuntu 18.04 with git 2.17.1 neither with bash nor zsh. If you want help with this, please provide more information on your (and your friends) OS and git version. If one of you uses windows, which client do you use? Are you using any other tool to interact with git? Btw. you provided the `github` and `gitlab` tag. Which one is it?

Answer (score 0):

If this is related to your OS, you should:

- try and launch a Ubutun environment (through Docker or, on Windows, WSL2)
- clone the repository there
- mkdir "Data_File"
- git mv "Data_File\ /CMakeLists.txt" "Data_File/CMakeLists.txt"
- add, commit and push back